# Spring-Data-REST: Custom serialization of @Embeddable in HAL

Tags: json, spring-data-rest, hateoas, hal

I have an entity which looks like this (I'll omit getters, setters and constuctors for the sake of brevity):

```
@Entity
public class System {
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "SYSTEMID", nullable = false)
    @Embedded
    private SystemId systemId;
}
```

with SystemId looking like this:

```
@Embeddable
@JsonSerialize(using = SystemIdSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = SystemIdDeserializer.class)
public class SystemId {
    @Column(name = "SYSTEMID", nullable = false)
    private String value;
}
```

My custom serializer does nothing but write out value, which works for 'normal' JSON, just not the HAL representation which looks like this:

```
{
    "systemId": {
        "content": "1"
    }
}
```

I would like to have it like this

```
{
    "systemId": "1"
}
```

as well.
Is there any way to do it? I've spent some time googling but wasn't successful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections) can help you...

```
@Projection(name="withSystemId", types = System.class)
public interface WithSystemId {

    @JsonProperty("systemId")
    @Value("#{target.systemId.value}")
    String getSysId();

    // Other getters of System properties...
}
```

Then try GET your `System`:

`http://localhost:8080/api/systems?projection=withSystemId`

**UPDATED**

Concerning the custom serializer - just add `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation to `systemId`:

```
@Entity
public class System {

    @Embedded
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private SystemId systemId;
}
```

Then you must get what you expect

```
{
    "systemId": "1"
}
```

And I assume that your serializer looks like this:

```
public class SystemIdSerializer extends StdSerializer<SystemId> {

    public SystemIdSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected SystemIdSerializer(Class<SystemId> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(SystemId id, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeNumberField("systemId", id.value());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

---

Working example is [here](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example8/model). See `Member` and nested `MemberSkill` classes. Then try to launch the app and GET http://localhost:8080/api/members

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, but shouldn't it be possible without a projection? When I post content with the custom serializer, Spring is able to deserialize it. I just don't understand why it isn't using the custom serializer.

Comment: @N4zroth Maybe it's necessary to register custom  serializer explicitly.. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @N4zroth no need to register custom serializer, just use `@JsonUnwrapped`.. I've updated my answer

Comment: Awesome, thanks, @JsonUnwrapped is doing exactly what I want. Thanks for the help!